# android engine for development

Tags: android

I work on a lot of closed source projects but often find myself extending the same classes, implementing the same libraries, doing the same things for caching and solving memory issues, and seeing other companies I work with facing the same issues

It makes me wonder if there are engines for android out there created for certain purposes. My cursory google search on this issue was unproductive

but I think this question is constructive because there is a real answer to this instead of discussion. Alternatively, what StackExchange site would this be a better question on?

Google Play Services and Volley are great examples and responses by google to certain problems such as but not limited to GPS/Positioning logic, network calls, bitmap caching, but I was wondering if there was anything more that is also maintained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have a few different problems that each have their own solutions.

> extending the same classes, [...]  doing the same things for caching and solving memory issues

Making your own library that contains these custom subclasses and caching implementations would probably suit your needs pretty well.

You may also want to learn how to create your own templates for Android Studio. Templates (such as the "new Master/Detail flow" default template) can be used to automatically generate classes and XML files to avoid spending time writing boilerplate code. [Here's a GitHub repo with a number of examples](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/AndroidStudioTemplate).

> implementing the same libraries

This sounds like your core complaint is that you want a way to automatically generate a base project of sort for your projects that might automatically include certain libraries, set up a package structure, etc. This can be accomplished using [Maven archetypes](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html).

If you want an example of how to create a Maven archetype, I would check out [Velcro](https://github.com/pieces029/velcro).